# Sending of encrypted message and encrypted audio video call with smack 4.4.0

Tags: android, smack, omemo

i am trying to use smack 4.4.0 with android. For now, here is what I can do:
-connect to the server
-authenticate me and send an unencrypted message

My server is ejabberd.

Now I want to use OMEMO to encrypt the messages. I see there is OpenGPG. I don’t know which is more effective, so I took OMEMO.
But I can’t send an encrypted message.
I’ve been looking for 4 days and trying to understand. Now I need help.
Here is the tutorial I followed: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/extensions/omemo.md

I’m desperate, really desperate.
Here are the dependencies I am using in android studio:

```
implementation ‘org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-sasl-provided: 4.4.0’
implementation ‘org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-resolver-dnsjava: 4.4.0’
implementation ‘org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-openpgp: 4.4.0’
implementation ‘org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-android: 4.4.0’
implementation ‘org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-im: 4.4.0’
implementation ‘org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-xmlparser-xpp3: 4.4.0’
// implementation ‘org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-jingle-old: 4.4.0’
/ * testImplementation ‘junit: junit: 4.13.2’
androidTestImplementation ‘androidx.test.ext: junit: 1.1.2’
androidTestImplementation ‘androidx.test.espresso: espresso-core: 3.3.0’ * /

implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-tcp: 4.4.0'
implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-android-extensions: 4.4.0'
implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack: smack-omemo-signal: 4.4.0'
```

In the tutorial I followed in https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/extensions/omemo.md, there is a Message message = encrypted.asMessage (contactsJid) instruction; but I can’t find the asMessage method in OmemoMessage.sent, so I don’t know what to do

Help me with an example or a tutorial for the smack.4.4.0 version or if I need to change dependencies in my build.gradle

Sincerely I hope a lot on you

PS: After that I want to implement the audio and video call: if I have sources or tutorials at the same time, I would be satisfied.

Thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are still searching for an answer;

Smack has some really nice integration tests, which show you how to use the API.
In case of OMEMO, there is for example [this file](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/smack-integration-test/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/omemo/MessageEncryptionIntegrationTest.java) which demonstrates usage of the API.